# Vectors - What is Magnitude, What is actually an vector?

Tags: vectors

first of all, I'm not that good at math, and I'm struggling with understanding the concept of "A vector", I've done some research, but I'm not sure if I did understand right the concept. So, a vector, in my own definition is a entity, something, which has a size and a direction. Like, throwing a ball from up to down... when it comes down, the vector is composed from the direction, which points to bottom, and the magnitude is the size we do have in this context, like the speed. Another example, on the previous one, we can aswell thinking to the action of throwing a ball from up to down as a vector which has the magnitude related to weight, and the direction. So, did I understand it or I'm missunderstanding it?

Comment: This is the motivation to define mathematical objects called "vectors". But you cannot take this as a "definition" because then you would have to also make sense of "magnitude" and "direction" (mathematically), which you know by *your* experience. But then to make sense of these two terms you would eventually end up needing the notion of "vectors" (as mathematical objects) in the first place. I would advise you to see some basic Linear Algebra books, where the notion of vectors will be given more intuitively and then an abstract theory would have been developed.

Comment: I suspect you would get an answer more to your liking by posting (or searching) physics.se instead.  It seems like you are first encountering things like velocity vectors and acceleration vectors in a physics context, and answerers over there will give you a physics answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you a formal answer, a bit informally. I'll first point to the (abstract) definition, then relate them to some familiar concept:

- mathematically speaking, a vector is a member of a vector space ([definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)). Essentially, if you have a collection of things, a "sum" operation defined on those things, as well as "scaling by a number" operation on those things, then you can "give that set a vector space structure" and call the elements of that set "vectors". My linear algebra teacher always said that also potatoes can be vectors, if you manage to sum potatoes and multiply them by scalars in a suitable way that respect all the requirements you found in the link above
- an example of vectors, according to this definition, are arrows in the plane that start at the origin of the plane, where the sum is defined by the parallelogram law (in such a way that the resulting vector starts at the origin too) and the multiplication of scalars definined as you would imagine. To be more concrete, i.e. to formally define an arrow, you can think of it as a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$, in the sense that the point $(x,y)$ corresponds to the arrow starting at $(0,0)$ and ending at $(x,y)$. Sum and multiplication by scalar are $(x,y)+(z,w):=(x+z,y+w)$, and $a\cdot (x,y):=(ax,ay)$
- so, now you know what a vector is. However, let me say something more, by making vectors more dynamic entities. There is another structure called affine space, that will hopefully clear things even better (or worse). An affine space is a set of points $S$, together with a vector space $V$ and an operation that makes vectors (*elements of $V$*) "act" on points (*elements of S*) in a standardized way ([definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Definition))
- as an example, $S$ could be a sheet of paper, say, $S = \mathbb{R}^2$, which you should imagine without origin and axis, and one could take $V$ to be the set of arrows from before, so, $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ as well. The action of vectors on points could be the following: $p+\overrightarrow{v}=q$, where $p=(x,y)$, a point, $\overrightarrow{v}=(v_x, v_y)$ a vector (arrow), and $q=(x+v_x, y+v_y)$. Here, although vectors and points are in the same set, you should imagine them as different entities: points belong to $S$, and get acted upon by vectors, belonging on $V$. Physically speaking, this is just the formalization of moving $p$ by $\overrightarrow{v}$ to $q$.

So, to complete, vectors may be often thought as things that can move things. However vectors can be very abstract things, in mathematics. If we are still on the plane before, vectors also have a magnitude (the distance of the tip of the arrow from the origin). The direction would be the line on which the vector lies.

I left a lot of things unsaid, let me know if I should expand some points.

Comment: If you want "potato" to be a vector, sure, the zero vector.

Comment: Do we need to define a vector space before defining a vector?

Comment: @mjw If a vector is a member of a vector space yes, what other formal ways are there to go about this?

Comment: In zero dimensions, "potato", in one dimension a scalar $a$, in two dimensions, an ordered pair $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2),$ etc.

Comment: The OP stated (more or less) that a vector has magnitude and direction.  That's a valid definition.

Comment: I reported the most common definition in modern mathematics, to my knowledge. Is it your point that you can call a vector whatever you want, as words are just words? Because in case, I agree, but I would say there may be multiple takes on this answer.

Comment: That was your linear algebra teacher's point.  But calling it by any name, only works in zero dimensions.

Comment: I think my teacher's point was that you can call potatoes vectors, if you find a way to sum them up. You'll never find a way to do so if you have six of them, so, in that case, I won't call them vectors.

Comment: Your teacher was right.  The vector space of potatoes has one vector, the potato vector.  $\alpha \cdot \textbf{potato} = \textbf{potato}$  and $\textbf{potato}+\textbf{potato} = \textbf{potato}.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130344/discussion-between-leonardo-and-mjw).

Comment: Thank you very much. I did understand a bit of what you have wrote me, but my math knowledges aren't that good so I haven't understand it how I would like to. But I appreciate that, thanks a lot =)